# What does the SQLiteOpenHelper class do with the context parameter?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, constructor

I am extending the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class. My constructor is

```
public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(
        context,         // ???
        "MyDatabase.db", // Database name
        null,            // Cursor factory
        1                // database version
    );
}
```

What does the SQLiteOpenHelper constructor do with the context information?

For my application, the constructor will behave the same regardless of the program state (context). Can I pass null in for the context with out any future problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you supply a null value, it will create an in-memory database instead but you'll need to supply null for the database name parameter as well so it's handled properly.

This is documented in the constructor documentation for context

> context to use to open or create the database name of the database
>   file, or null for an in-memory database

Also, if you view the source code of the SQLiteHelper class itself, you will see it uses the mName value to decide whether to use mContext.  View the source code online here:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#SQLiteOpenHelper.0mContext

Comment: Thank you! This makes more sense now. I had never heard of grepcode and I think that site and I will become well acquainted!

Comment: rookie question: isn't the database name already being used for the second parameter?
What would go in for the context then?

Comment: The context can be the activity or the application itself.

Comment: From the source code: context is used for: 1) get full path of the db. 2) invoke openOrCreateDatabase on context object.